# Why does Wei WuXian look like Mo XuanYu?

Tags: mo-dao-zu-shi

What was the purpose of their bodies looking almost identical to each other? Was it just the animator's decision or was it in the novel?

[image: wei wuxian vs mo xuanyu]

The top image is Wei Wuxian and the bottom one is him in Mo Xuanyu's body.

Comment: This bothered me too like Mo Xuanyu looks in terms of his outfit and physical look is almost exactly like Wei Ying, personality is the same, and they both use the same kind of dark magic, like how did no one else not recognize him

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it was the animator's decision. All we know is when Wei Ying made comments about Mo Xuan Yu's body, he noted that Mo Xuan Yu was shorter than him in his previous life and that he was handsome as well.

There was no note on that in the novel. In the novel, he was extremely surprised when Lan Zhan was able to recognize him, so actually according to the story, they aren't supposed to look alike at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was noted in the novel or extra materials that due to the influence of Wuxian's soul and the fact that the body LITERALLY became his, it immediately started taking the shape of his own body, little by little.

Comment: Could you give us a source? As in which chapter/extra was it mentioned?